# I want to replace a text appearing multiple times in a file at once

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to replace a text in a file in linux

That kind of line will appear multiple times and also in different kind of format

Example:

12345 = yourself : 1376*5435

96235 = yourself : 6723*8112

These kind of text will appear multiple times in the file the only thing common will be "yourself" i.e. the middle text

and I need to replace it with the below text

" ### = yourself : ### "

Please help me do this task at once

Answer (score 1):

If the number of digits is exactly these you provided in the examples, you could use this `sed` command (considering `filename` to be the name of your file):

```sh
sed -E 's/[0-9]{5}\ =\ yourself\ :\ [0-9]{4}\*[0-9]{4}/### = yourself : ###/' filename
```

If the number of digits will vary, just change it to:

```sh
sed -E 's/[0-9].+\ =\ yourself\ :\ [0-9].+\*[0-9].+/### = yourself : ###/' filename
```

I used the following input to test this:

```
12345 = yourself : 1376*5435
54353 = yourself : 3245*3221
96235 = yourself : 6723*8112
```

Ps: there's no need to escape spaces inside the sed command. My bad. Also, if you want to change it inplace, pass the flag `-i`.

Comment: The exact statement is like   " 1011 0011 1001 1101 = Yourself :  0x37628332 "